# Convert one object to another in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am new in C#, dotnet core. I am getting data from database like below. This data is very flat. I need to convert to another object.

```
public class Lead
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public short LeadCreatorId { get; set; }

        public short LeadOwnerId { get; set; }

        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public LeadPriority Priority { get; set; }

        public LeadStatus Status { get; set; }

        public long LeadCustomerId { get; set; }  

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string MobileNo { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to convert it to below object.

```
public class LeadDto
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public short LeadCreatorId { get; set; }

        public short LeadOwnerId { get; set; }

        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public LeadPriority Priority { get; set; }

        public LeadStatus Status { get; set; }

        public LeadCustomer LeadCustomer { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

Where LeadCustomer is like below -

```
public class LeadCustomer{

            public long Id { get; set; }

            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

            public string MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

How can I easily do that? Can I use dto for the conversion.

Comment: [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) is the easiest way, although not necessarily the most performant.

Comment: Interface is the first thing comes to my mind, but it depends on what you're going to do with LeadDto and LeadCustomer object.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are many many mapper libraries out in the internet. To name a few

- automapper
- mapster
- emitmapper

All of them have their own pros and cons.
I would personally feel writing your own mapper methods would be worth it as you will have complete control of what you write.

I agree it could take some time but it doesn't take so long.

Answer (score 3):

Since `LeadDto` and `LeadCustomer` depend on `Lead`:

One option would be to add a constructor to `LeadDto` and `LeadCustomer` that take the `Lead` object as a param and map to the properties.

Another option would be to create a static extension method.

```
public static LeadDto ToLeadDto(this Lead lead)
{
   return new LeadDto(){
      this.Id = lead.Id;
      // Etc..
   }
}
```

Then you can use like

```
LeadDto myObj = someLead.ToLeadDto();
```

And yet another option would be to use a library such as AutoMapper.  I have never used it, and is overkill for your stated need, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

A simple straightforward approach could be to have a function on Lead class to return the object you need.

```
public class Lead
{
    //// your properties
    public LeadDto GetOtherObject()
    {
        LeadDto object = new LeadDto();
        ////Map properties from this to object
        return object;
    }
}
```

Else you can have static utility function if above approach doesn't seems right in given context.

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static LeadDto GetOtherObject(Lead leadObject)
    {
        LeadDto object = new LeadDto();
        ////Map properties from leadObject to object
        return object;
    }
}
```

If the coupling of `LeadDto` is strictly only with Lead, you can have a `Lead` object as parameter itself in constructor of `LeadDto`.

While mapping properties from Lead to LeadDto, please make sure you consider `LeadPriority` and `LeadStatus` with caution as they might work differently based on whether they are structs or classes.

Answer (score 1):

As @G_S suggested I have used automapper like below -

```
        CreateMap<Lead, LeadDto>()
            .ForMember(desc => desc.LeadCustomer, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
            {
                return new LeadCustomer()
                {
                    Id = src.LeadCustomerId,
                    FirstName = src.FirstName,
                    LastName = src.LastName,
                    EmailAddress = src.EmailAddress,
                    MobileNo = src.MobileNo
                };
            }));
```

Comment: You also need a map from Lead to LeadCustomer and `ForMember(desc => desc.LeadCustomer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src)`.